# How to get a "PCWSTR" object from a Path or String?

Tags: winapi, rust, windows-rs

I'm using the `IDesktopWallpaper::SetWallpaper` method from the windows crate. The second argument to this method is a `PCWSTR`(pointer) to the full path of an image that's meant to be set as the wallpaper. The problem is that the `PCWSTR` object is meant to be of type `*const u16` not `*const String`. How can I get a `PCWSTR` object from a Path/String?

```
let path = "Path_to_image.jpg".to_string();
let ptr = &path as *const String;
let wallpaper = PCWSTR::from_raw(ptr); 
//                               ^^^  expected raw pointer `*const u16` 
//                                         found raw pointer `*const String`

unsafe { desktop.SetWallpaper(None, wallpaper)};
```

Comment: If the source is a string literal you can simply make use of the [`w!`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/macro.w.html) macro, i.e. `desktop.SetWallpaper(None, w!("Path_to_image.jpg"));`.

Comment: @IInspectable For this simple example, it works. However, this solution isn't enough for the overall scope of my project.

Comment: @IInspectable I found that there is a type "HSTRING" that can be turned into a "PCWSTR". However, I don't think I can initialize it with a specific string. I can only create an empty one.

Comment: `HSTRING` has a [`From`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.HSTRING.html#impl-From%3C%26str%3E-for-HSTRING) implementation for `&str` (and a number of other Rust string types). So either use `HSTRING` as an intermediary, or `encode_utf16().chain(iter::once(0)).collect::<Vec<_>>()` to get a buffer you can `as_ptr()` to construct a `PCWSTR`.

Comment: @IInspectable Wow, I didn't even see the `From`. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Regarding strings, Rust and Windows couldn't possibly disagree more. There are always going to be conversions involved when using Rust on Windows, and the best you can hope for is a crate that does this for you.

The [windows](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate doesn't just provide Rust mappings for Windows' API surface, it also contains a tiny library that addresses common issues when programming Windows with Rust, amongst which is string handling. A *lot* of thought went into string handling, and the result may seem somewhat anticlimactic: **All** string constants can be represented as [`HSTRING`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.HSTRING.html) instances.

Consequently, `HSTRING` is the pivot point for string conversions in Rust for Windows. Its implementation has a sleuth of [`From`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.HSTRING.html#trait-implementations) trait implementations for Rust string types (all, I believe), with `From` implementations of all other Windows string types for `HSTRING`.

In this case, if `path` is of type [`Path`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/path/struct.Path.html), you can construct an `HSTRING` from it and pass it by reference. Everything else happens due to implicit `From` trait invocations (namely [`From<&HSTRING> for PCWSTR`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.PCWSTR.html#impl-From%3C%26HSTRING%3E-for-PCWSTR)):

```rust
unsafe { desktop.SetWallpaper(None, &HSTRING::from(path.as_os_str())) };
```

---

#### v0.44.0+

[v0.44.0](https://crates.io/crates/windows/0.44.0) (released 2023-01-12) introduced an [`impl From<&Path> for HSTRING`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/core/struct.HSTRING.html#impl-From%3C%26Path%3E-for-HSTRING), allowing us to further simplify the code:

```rust
unsafe { desktop.SetWallpaper(None, &HSTRING::from(&path)) };
```

This is purely for convenience. Internally, `From<&Path>` calls `as_os_str()` on our behalf and subsequently delegates to the `From<&OsStr>` implementation.